# DispatcherTimer and Show Modal Window

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's see if anyone can explain me this behaviour and maybe how can I solve this. I have a `WPF` app, and in my ViewModel I have a `DispatcherTimer`. In that ViewModel i have a command to show a modal window, something like this:

```
private void ShowWindowCommandExecuted()
{
     wnNewWindow window = new wnNewWindow();
     window.ShowDialog();
}
```

When i call this Command from a button, the new window is shown and the `DispatcherTimer` keeps running in the background. So far so good. The problem is when i try to show the window from the `DispatcherTimer` like this:

```
DispatcherTimer timerInstrucciones;
timerInstrucciones = new DispatcherTimer();
timerInstrucciones.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
timerInstrucciones.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
     wnNewWindow window = new wnNewWindow();
     window.ShowDialog();     
};
timerInstrucciones.Start();
```

In this case, the new window is also shown, but as long it is visible, the `DispatcherTimer` stops "ticking". I understand the `DispatcherTimer` runs in the UI thread, but why it behaves in a different way in this case?

Comment: The difference is that in the latter case you are blocking the Tick event handler. A DispatcherTimer won't continue and fire another Tick event unless the previous Tick handler has completed execution.

Comment: Ok @Clemens, now I understand it! It should have been obvious to me. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Did you try the BeginInvoke solution suggested in the answer?

Comment: I'm on it, but using it the tick won't fire,i don't know why

Comment: @Clemens ok,now i understand what is happening I'm going to use a `System.Timers.Timer` instead. Thanks for your help. Anyway, i don't know why the `BeginInvoke` solution didn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, `ShowDialog` is a modal dialog that will block the calling thread, and show the dialog. It will also block interaction with the parent/owning window too.

As long as you close the Modal Dialog, the UI-Thread is blocked. Because its a `DispatcherTimer`, it belongs to the Window's Dispatcher and runs in the same thread. So if this thread is blocked, the `DispatcherTimer` stops running.

**UPDATE BASED ON YOUR COMMENTS:**

I haven't went through any documentation on this, but the basic difference would be `DispatcherTimer` will run `Synchronously` and not in `Asynchronous` way.

**Won't block the Dispatcher:**

```
 timerInstrucciones.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
           {
               wnNewWindow mn = new wnNewWindow();
               mn.ShowDialog();
           }));
        };
```

**Will block the Dispatcher:**

```
timerInstrucciones.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
           {
               wnNewWindow mn = new wnNewWindow();
               mn.ShowDialog();
           }));
        };
```

Since, `Dispatcher` will `Invoke` the `Event` on every n seconds, `Event` cannot be called anymore, if the thread got blocked for any operation inside the calling `Event` .

Comment: I know that showing a modal window stops the execution in the calling code (that's why it's modal), But in my example, showing a modal window does not stop the `DispatcherTimer`. It only stops it if I show the modal window from inside the `DispatcherTimer` code,that's what I don't understand

Comment: @Pikoh Updated my answer.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @Pikoh `ShowDialog` has to be called inside `BeginInvoke` of `Tick` event. Make sure you haven't called it anywhere outside.

Comment: The problem is not the `ShowDialog`. If i use this code `timerInstrucciones.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
           {
               Debug.Print("test tick");
           }));
        };` the code is never executed...

Comment: Anyway, now i understand what is happening I'm going to use a `System.Timers.Timer` instead, although i don´t know why your `BeginInvoke` code does not work? Thank you very much for your help, i'll accept your answer.:)